# How could I make the syncfusion rich text editor to put spaces instead of the `&nbsp;`?

Tags: api, vuejs2, text-editor, space, syncfusion

How could I make the syncfusion rich text editor to put spaces instead of the `&nbsp;`?

The editor puts the `&nbsp;` instead of spaces. This behavior prevents the css `word-break: break-word;` from working properly. I.e. instead of keeping words on the same line without splitting them, the whole text is treated as one word.

E.g. if I type `qqqq` , then copy and paste the content of editor I will visually see the following: `qqqq qqqq`, while the `this.$refs.sfRichTextEditor.instance.value` will produce the following result: `<p>qqqq&nbsp;<span style="background-color: unset; text-align: inherit;">qqqq&nbsp;</span></p>`.

Would it maybe be possible to make the syncfusion to use the `<pre>` instead of the `<p>` and the spaces instead of the `&nbsp;`?

So, my main problem is that I want the word break for the content produced from the editor to work properly.

An obvious solution may be to just manually edit the value before saving it. I.e. substitute the `&nbsp;` with the spaces. But that feels hacky and error prone (though I cant think of a case when it would produce an error).

I would expect there to be an API for that purpose. I tried to Google and to browse [the documenation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/documentation/rich-text-editor/getting-started/), but did not find anything which would allow to configure the spaces behavior. If I am missing it, could you point me towards it, please?

**UPDATE**

If I just type `qqq qqq`, then I am getting the expected space. But typing `qqq` , copying it and then pasting it back produces the `qqq&nbsp;`. So, the issue occurs only when the text is pasted. Is it an expected behavior which I can do nothing about?

Comment: In HTML multiple spaces are reduces to a single space, and here a final space might be trimmed/discarded. The technique to prevent that is to use a hard space `U+00A0` or `&nbsp;` (non-breaking space).  Maybe you can replace the space in keypress with `'\x0A'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was caused by the non-zero width space added to the Rich Text Editor for the cursor pointer, and it can be fixed by replacing the non-zero width space with an empty value in the Rich Text Editor content before saving the value in the database, or by simply using white-space:pre-wrap CSS styles for the RichTextEditor content element.

You can follow either of the following solutions.

Using CSS styles:

.e-richtexteditor.e-rte-tb-expand .e-rte-content,

```
  .e-richtexteditor.e-rte-tb-expand .e-source-content {

    white-space: pre-wrap;

  }
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vlk2lx?file=index.html,index.ts

Using Regex:

Use the below code before saving into the database after getting the RichTextEditor value.

// using regex

var text = defaultRTE.getHtml();

var replaced = text.replace(/ /g, ' '); // Removed   from RichTextEditor value

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vlk2lx-obq9ds?file=index.html,index.ts